# How to insert upload file data and form data from view to database in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a create function to insert view data to database. The view has a upload file textbox along with other textboxes. How do I bind form data and insert the uploaded file in bytes to a table?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Princial_name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Princial_name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Princial_name)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.p_campus)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.p_campus)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.p_campus)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.filepath)
    <input type="file" name="postedFile" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,Princial_name,p_campus,filepath,filedata")] grant grant)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase postedFile;
    byte[] bytes;
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
    {
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        grant.id = Guid.NewGuid();
         db.Entry(grant).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //add filepath
        db.Entry(grant).Property("filepath").CurrentValue =  Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        db.Entry(grant).Property("filedata").CurrentValue = bytes;
        db.grant.Add(grant);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
     return View(grant);
}
```

The controller cannot insert both form data and upload file data to database. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Your not reading the value form the file input (all you have done ins initialize a new instance of `HttpPostedFileBase`). Add a `HttpPostedFileBase postedFile` parameter in your POST method signature so its bound.

Comment: I added HttpPostedFileBase postedFile to Create() function as second parameter and it didn't work. Do I need to modify the route configuration or somewhere?

Comment: No - Are you saying that `postedFile` is `null` (it works fine)?

Comment: The Create function only takes one parameter, either bind the form controls or postedFile.

Comment: What?? - `public ActionResult Create(grant grant, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)` - but your editing data so ALWAYS use a view model, and that view model will contain just the properties your editing plus a `HttpPostedFileBase` property

Comment: I am new to MVC and  I am trying to add view model data and the postedFile data to database table using public ActionResult Create(grant grant, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile) but it does not work. So the Create function can only take view model but not a extra parameter HttpPostedFileBase postedFile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164715/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user788448).

Answer (score 0):

put a second parameter

```
Create([Bind(Include = "id,Princial_name,p_campus,filepath,filedata")] grant grant, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
```